# Bound the variance of the product of two random varables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables, covariance

For two random variables $X$ and $Y$ show that the following inequality holds

$$\mathrm{Var}(XY)\leq 2\|Y\|_{\infty}^{2}\mathrm{Var}(X)+2\|X\|_{\infty}^{2}\mathrm{Var}(Y).$$

Well first I tried to show it for just indicators functions by I couldn't even show that. 
Any tips?

Comment: No here I am not assuming they are independent.

Comment: In the general case, $$Var(XY)= 2 \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(Y) \text{Cov}(X,Y)-\text{Cov}(X,Y)^2+\mu _{2,2}+2 \mu _{1,2} \mathbb{E}(X)+2 \mu _{2,1} \mathbb{E}(Y)+\text{Var}(Y) (\mathbb{E}[X])^2+\text{Var}(X) (\mathbb{E}[Y])^2$$ ... may serve as a useful starting point.

Comment: sorry but what are $\mu_{2,2}$ and $\mu_{2,1}$ suppose to be?

Comment: Sorry - I should have specified. They denote the product central moments: $$\mu _{r,s}=E\left[(X-E[X])^r (Y-E[Y])^s\right]$$

Comment: I think you need to assume that the variables are bounded, $a.s.$

Comment: @Eupraxis1981  Well I don't think you need to assume that they are bounded since if say $X$ is unbounded and if $Y\neq 0$ then the right hand side is infinite and the inequality still holds and in the case that $Y=0$ then both sides are zero and the result still holds. So yes it is fair to assume that they are both bounded a.s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $U$ and $V$ are two random variables, then the inequality 
$$\mathrm{Var}(U+V)\leqslant 2\mathrm{Var}(U)+2\mathrm{Var}(V)$$
takes place. Using this inequality with $U:=(X-\mathbb E[X])Y$ and $V:=\mathbb E[X]Y$, we obtain that 
$$\mathrm{Var}(XY)\leqslant 2\mathrm{Var}((X-\mathbb E[X])Y)+2\mathrm{Var}(\mathbb E[X]Y).$$
Since 
\begin{align}\mathrm{Var}((X-\mathbb E[X])Y)&=\mathbb E\left[((X-\mathbb E[X])Y)^2\right]-
\left(\mathbb E\left[(X-\mathbb E[X])Y\right]\right)^2\\
&\leqslant \mathbb E\left[((X-\mathbb E[X])Y)^2\right]\\
&\leqslant \mathbb E\left[(X-\mathbb E[X])^2\right]\lVert Y\rVert_\infty^2\\
&=\mathrm{Var}(X)\lVert Y\rVert_\infty^2,
\end{align}
we have showed the inequality 
$$\mathrm{Var}(XY)\leqslant 2\mathrm{Var}(X)\lVert Y\rVert_\infty^2+2(\mathbb E[X])^2\mathrm{Var}(Y).$$