# Bounding second moment of product of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

> $X$ and $Y$ are two dependent Gaussian random variables with finite means $\mu_x,\mu_y$, variances $\sigma_x^2,\sigma_y^2$, and covariance $\rho$. Prove $\mathbb{E}[X^2Y^2]$ is finite.

**My effort:** It is equivalent to show that $\text{Var}[XY]$  is finite. There is a [bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043082/bound-the-variance-of-the-product-of-two-random-varables) on the variance of $XY$ which does not work here since $X$ and $Y$ are not bounded. Another way might be to use this pdf of the [product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html) and show that the integral is finite. Although it works for zero means, we can say even if the mean is not zero we are OK. I thought there might be a better solution. Any idea?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwartz would allow you to bound this using the fourth moments, so hopefully they are finite (which indeed you would need anyway since if X=Y, the expression reduces to the fourth moment of X)

Comment: @E-A Thanks for your comment. Can you please expand on that a little? Fourth moments of what? If you are referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality , that gives the reverse.

Comment: @E-A If you mean fourth moments of $X$ and $Y$, of course, they are finite since they are Gaussians with finite mean and variance.

Comment: With the information given, the joint density function $f(x,y)$ can be expressed and the integral of $x^2y^2f(x,y)$ can be calculated.

Comment: As E-A pointed out you just use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, which gives you $\mathbb{E}[X^2Y^2] \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^4]\mathbb{E}[Y^4]}$, and the RHS is finite as mentioned. This is most general - only use the fact that they are marginally normal, and it does not require them to have a joint normality.

Comment: @Susan_Math123 yeah, BGM wrote it out (plug in $X^2$ instead of $X$ in the wikipedia page, and same with $Y$); also herb, technically while I am sure these are meant to be jointly gaussian, it is not explicitly stated so we don't actually know the joint density function from the given question; we just know that they are marginally gaussian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should probably write it as a full answer so that the question is answered: the result immediately follows from Cauchy-Schwartz inequality (as BGM wrote out in the comments) $\mathbb{E}X^2Y^2 \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}X^4\mathbb{E}Y^4}$, and for Gaussians the fourth moment is finite.