# About variance inequalities: $V[A1_F+B1_{F^c}]\leq V[A]+V[B]$, $V[A1_F]\leq V[A]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

Let $A$ and $B$ be two random variables and $F$ be any event. Is it true that $V[A\cdot 1_F+B\cdot 1_{F^c}]\leq V[A]+V[B]$ ? Here $V[\cdot]$ denotes the variance operator, $F^c$ the complementary of $F$, and $1$ the indicator function.

Do we also have $V[A\cdot 1_F]\leq V[A]$ ?

I know the variance inequalities from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294252/inequality-on-variance-of-sum) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043082/bound-the-variance-of-the-product-of-two-random-varables), but I wonder about the existence of tighter inequalities when indicator functions are involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both inequalities are false. Indeed, suppose that $\mathbb P(A=x)=1$ for some nonzero $x\in\mathbb R$. Then $\textrm{Var}(A)=\mathbb E(A-x)^2=0$ whereas
$$
\textrm{Var}(A\cdot 1_F)=x^2\textrm{Var}(1_F)=x^2\mathbb P(F)\mathbb P(F^c),
$$
which is greater than $0$ whenever $F$ is an event satisfying $0<\mathbb P(F)<1$.
This yields a counterexample to the second inequality, and taking $B=0$ in addition yields a counterexample to the first inequality.

---

If a more concrete counterexample is more to your taste, take $A$ to be uniformly distributed on $[0,2]$ and let $F$ be the event that $A$ is greater than $1$. Then
$$
\textrm{Var}(A\cdot 1_F)=\int_{1}^{2}x^2\ \frac{dx}{2}-\Bigl(\int_{1}^{2}x\ \frac{dx}{2}\Bigr)^2=\frac{29}{48},\qquad \textrm{Var}\ A=\frac{1}{3}=\frac{16}{48},
$$
contradicting your second inequality.